# How to mock __ function in Vitest?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs, vitest

I'm struggling to understand how to mock a localization function `__()` and even if that's the right solution to my problem.

I am using Laravel for my backend and Vue for my front end and Inertiajs for the glue and I want to start testing my components with Vitest. But my tests are failing:

`TypeError: _ctx.__ is not a function`

Example component:

```
<script setup>
import Checkbox from '@/Components/Checkbox.vue';
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError.vue';
import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel.vue';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import { useForm, usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';


const user = usePage().props.auth.user;

const form = useForm({
    inboxable: user.inboxable ?? true,
});

const saveForm = (() => {
    form.patch(route('privacy.update'), {
        preserveScroll: true,
    });
});

</script>

<template>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h2 class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">{{__('user.privacyTitle')}}</h2>

            <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
                {{__('user.privacyDescription')}}

            </p>
        </header>

        <div>

  </div>


        <form @submit.prevent="saveForm" class="mt-6 space-y-6">
            <div>
                <InputLabel for="inboxable" :value="__('user.privacyInboxable')" />
                <Checkbox id="inboxable" v-model="form.inboxable" :checked="form.inboxable" />

                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.inboxable" />
            </div>

            <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                <PrimaryButton :disabled="form.processing">{{__('user.privacySave')}}</PrimaryButton>

                <Transition enter-from-class="opacity-0" leave-to-class="opacity-0" class="__ition ease-in-out">
                    <p v-if="form.recentlySuccessful" class="text-sm text-gray-600">{{__('user.profileConfirmed')}}</p>
                </Transition>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</template>
```

This is using another library called [Lingua](https://github.com/cyberwolf-studio/lingua) which converts Laravel's lang files into JS so they can be used in components. Lingua is added in app.js and makes the translation function `__()` globally available.

At this stage I don't need to test that the function returns the correct data so I'm thinking I should mock the function perhaps?

My `vite.config`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import path from 'path';
import { run } from 'vite-plugin-run'
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl'

export default defineConfig({
    esbuild: {
        jsxFactory: 'h',
        jsxFragment: 'Fragment'
      },
    plugins: [
        basicSsl(),
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        run({
            name: "generate translations",
            run: ['php', 'artisan', 'lingua:generate'],
            pattern: ['resources/lang/**', 'lang/**'],
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        hmr: {
          host: "192.168.10.1",
          https: true,
        },
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        https: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'lingua-js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor/cyberwolfstudio/lingua/dist/index.js')
        },
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: "jsdom",
      },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've 'solved' the issue but still unclear why I got the error.

In my app I am also using InertiaJs and in this component I am using both `usepage()` and `useForm()`.

Once I had mocked these in addition to mocking `__()` the error has gone away and the test passes.

Why the error message referred me to `__()` and not the Inertia methods, I still don't understand.

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import path from 'path';
import { run } from 'vite-plugin-run'
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl'

export default defineConfig({
    esbuild: {
        jsxFactory: 'h',
        jsxFragment: 'Fragment'
      },
    plugins: [
        basicSsl(),
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        run({
            name: "generate translations",
            run: ['php', 'artisan', 'lingua:generate'],
            pattern: ['resources/lang/**', 'lang/**'],
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        hmr: {
          host: "192.168.10.1",
          https: true,
        },
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        https: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'lingua-js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor/cyberwolfstudio/lingua/dist/index.js')
        },
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: "happy-dom",
        setupFiles: ['./vitestSetupFile.js'],
      },
});
```

vitestSetupFile.js

```
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils';

//mocking Lingua
config.global.mocks.__ = (key) => key;

// Mocking useForm and usePage from inertiajs
vi.mock('@inertiajs/vue3', () => ({
    useForm: () => ({
      inboxable: true,
      errors: {}
    }),
    usePage: () => ({
      props: {
        auth: {
          user: {
            inboxable: true, // Example
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  }));
```